Can't give backgroundcolor transparent between keyboard and input field - React Naitve
I am using the KeyboardAvoidingView , and the keyboardVerticalOffset prop is creating extra space between the keyboard and input field. I've tried setting the background color to transparent, but it's not working. I've even applied a transparent background color to the ScrollView and SafeAreaProvider in App.tsx, but the issue persists.

CreateAccount.tsx
<KeyboardAvoidingView
                            style={{ flex: 1,backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}
                            behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : 'height'}
                            keyboardVerticalOffset={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 130 : 85}
                        >
                            <ScrollView style={styles.scrollViewContainer} showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false} keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled">
                                <CreateAccountYourInformation formikProps={formikProps} formInputRefs={formInputRefs} />
</ScrollView>
                        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
...
scrollViewContainer: {
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        padding: 16,
        flex: 1,
        height: '100%',
    },


App.tsx
 <SafeAreaProvider style={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}>
            <PublicProviders>
                <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" backgroundColor="transparent" translucent />
                <AppProvider>
                    <PaperProvider theme={Theme}>
                        <NavigationContainer>
                            <RootNavigator />
                        </NavigationContainer>
                    </PaperProvider>
                    {Platform.OS == 'ios' ? (
                        <InputAccessoryView nativeID={inputAccessoryViewID}>
                            <View style={{ justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'flex-end', backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
                                <Button mode="text" onPress={() => Keyboard.dismiss()}>
                                    <Text style={commonStyles.buttonText}>Done</Text>
                                </Button>
                            </View>
                        </InputAccessoryView>
                    ) : null}
                </AppProvider>
            </PublicProviders>
        </SafeAreaProvider>

I tried giving background color transparent to keyboardAvoidingView but it doesn't work ,I attached screenshot you see above done text there is a default white space background showing, I don't know how to solve the background color to transparent. Please help me with that issue.

And how does it look when the keyboard is closed?
